# How to combine the output of two files into single in python?

Tags: python, file, python-2.7

My code looks like this:
Right now my code outputs two text file named absorbance.txt and energy.txt separately. I need to modify it so that it outputs only one file named combined.txt such that every line of combined.txt has two values separated by comma. The first value must be from absorbance.txt and second must be from energy.txt. ( I apologize if anyone is confused by my writting, Please comment if you need more clarification)

```
g = open("absorbance.txt", "w")
h = open("Energy.txt", "w")

ask = easygui.fileopenbox()
f = open( ask, "r")
a = f.readlines()
bg = []
wavelength = []
for string in a:

    index_j = 0
    comma_count = 0
    for j in string:
        index_j += 1

        if j == ',':
            comma_count += 1
            if comma_count == 1:

                slicing_point = index_j
                t = string[slicing_point:]
                new_str = string[:(slicing_point- 1)]
                new_energ = (float(1239.842 / int (float(new_str))) * 8065.54)
                print >>h, new_energ


import math
list = []
for i in range(len(ref)):


    try:
        ans = ((float (ref[i]) - float (bg[i])) / (float(sample[i]) - float(bg[i])))
        print ans
        base= 10  
        final_ans =  (math.log(ans, base))
    except:
        ans = -1 * ((float (ref[i]) - float (bg[i])) / (float(sample[i]) - float(bg[i])))
        print ans
        base= 10  
        final_ans =  (math.log(ans, base))

    print >>g, final_ans
```

Comment: `combined.write([x+","+y+"\n" for x in file1.readlines()] for y in file2.readlines()]`

Comment: @WajdiFarhani, `"\n"%` doesn't look like valid Python syntax to me.

Comment: sorry for that, you can delete it

Comment: ya it did not worked for me, invalid syntax!

Comment: @Kevin, do you think this is a duplicate question? I am new to python and stack overflow. I don't know why some random person down-voted my question? - Any suggestions for that so I could improve in my next question

Comment: Providing sample input and output is usually a good idea. And see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Robert's approach, but aiming to keep control flow as simple as possible.

absorbance.txt:

```
Hello
How are you
I am fine
Does anybody want a peanut?
```

energy.txt:

```
123
456
789
```

Code:

```
input_a = open("absorbance.txt")
input_b = open("energy.txt")
output = open("combined.txt", "w")
for left, right in zip(input_a, input_b):
    #use rstrip to remove the newline character from the left string
    output.write(left.rstrip() + ", " + right)

input_a.close()
input_b.close()
output.close()
```

combined.txt:

```
Hello, 123
How are you, 456
I am fine, 789
```

Note that the fourth line of absorbance.txt was not included in the result, because energy.txt does not have a fourth line to go with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can open both text files and append them to the new text file as shown below. This is what I gave based on your question, not necessarily the code your provided.

```
combined = open("Combined.txt","w")    
with open(r'Engery.txt', "rU") as EnergyLine:
    with open(r'Absorbance.txt', "rU") as AbsorbanceLine:
        for line in EnergyLine:
            Eng = line[:-1]
            for line2 in AbsorbanceLine:
                Abs = line2[:-1]
                combined.write("%s,%s\n" %(Eng,Abs))
                break
combined.close()
```

Comment: Won't this only write one line?

Comment: It works for me. Did you try to compile it on your side to verify?

Comment: it worked for me, thanks ! Is there a way I can only output combined.txt and not other two files!

Comment: Do you mean output the contents of the Combined.txt?

Comment: yes! When I run this code what i get( i mean what outputs on my desktop) is three files one absorbance.txt, next one is energy.txt and ohter is combined.txt. I want to modify it so that it only outputs combined.txt on my desktop

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong on this. You need the energy.txt and absorbance.txt files because based on your question you are reading in from these files. Without it you don't obtain any information.

Comment: Friendly reminder, if the question is answered, please accept an answer for future users! Thanks!